# Localizing RSS Feed Dates

Tags: php, rss

I am building a site with one feature that consolidates various discussions forums/feeds from a number of different sites into a single feed.  Everything is working well, except two sites don't always display dates, but rather 'relative text'.  For example, one site, when a post was made today, displays Today at 12:00 pm.  Another uses '18 hours and 14 minutes ago'.  Those two sites are www.mudconnect.com and www.mudbytes.net

The code for these two feeds can be found [here](http://www.mudlistings.com/date_problem_code.txt).  An example of the feed can be seen [here](http://mudlistings.com/index.php/community/multi-forums-feed).

Everything works fine until the server time rolls over to a new day, then the mudconnect ("Today") posts are shown as the current server day instead of the previous day.

Eg. 
Server time 5pm - Today at 11pm = Sept. 4th at 11pm
Server time 1am - Today at 11pm = Sept. 5th at 11pm

I know this is not something super complex, but for whatever reason I just have a mental block here.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  The programming language is PHP 7.  I can supply the entire PHP script if desired.

Thanks!

Comment: Server Time:

timedatectl status | grep "Time zone"
Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)

Comment: always a good idea to post any relevant code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$string = '18 hours and 14 minutes ago';
$regex = '#\d+\s\w+#';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

$date = new DateTime();
echo 'current date = '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

foreach ($matches[0] as $modify) {
    $date->modify('-'.$modify);
}

echo 'modified date = '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Hopefully you can follow that! This will output :

```
current date = 2017-09-06 17:16:39 

modified date = 2017-09-05 23:02:39
```

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/LL4R0

Answer (score 0):

> Please note: Different web site servers may operate on different time
>   zones, and thus the post times displayed may not coincide with what is
>   shown on the individual forum sites.  We've normalized them to all use
>   the same time zone (EST).
>   http://mudlistings.com/index.php/community/multi-forums-feed

All of the posts in the RSS feed are already "normalized" to EST and listed by order of newest post.

If you are trying to list this data inline with other feeds, simply convert the other feed's timestamps to EST and then they will all be in the same timezone.

If your server's timezone is not EST, then you can add/subtract hours from the feed's data to match your server.